# How can I use the CLI in Windows to tweak Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0

I have successfully installed Magento 2 on WAMP and its running perfectly fine. How can I now use the CLI in Windows to tweak Magento 2. Is this something to do with composer?

Answer (score 1):

You can run any magento command from windows CMD.

For example:

> php bin/magento cache:status

For more details, [refer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html) this.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I now use the CLI in Windows to tweak Magento 2

You can run the commands by using windows CMD

```
d:
cd Xamp\htdocs\mymagento\bin
```

later run required commands like `php magento setup:upgrade`

if it is not working ( Some times php is not working as global )

```
d:
cd Xamp\php
php "Xamp\htdocs\yourmagento\bin" magento setup:upgrade
```

Make sure the paths should be based on your naming conventions

For more reference

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete tutorial how you can install Magento 2 on Windows platform. Also, you'll be able to learn how you can install Composer, make PHP environment variable and use CMD for Magento 2 CLI Commands.

https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-install-magento-2-php7-localhost/

Answer (score 0):

you can run this command by CMD

if php is not global then use this
php.exe "\bin\magento" setup:upgrade(use quote as it is)

if php is global then 
cd \bin and run command
 magento setup:upgrade